# Python - Can't copy elements in a stack from another class

Tags: python, class, oop, stack

I have this python program that is a simple stack implementation. It simply pushes, pops, and displays elements.

The program is doing well whenever it pushes, pops, and displays the user inputted elements.

But my problem is, I can't seem to print a copy of the elements. Whenever I'm trying to make a copy, it displays `[]`

Here is the source code:

```
from os import system, name
from time import sleep

    def main():

        choice = int(input(" \t Enter your choice: "))
        clearScreen()

        if choice == 1:
            item = input("\n Enter element to push: ")
            s.push(item)
    
class Stack():
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.stack = []

    def length(self):
        return len(self.stack)

    def isEmpty(self):
        if self.stack == []:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    
    def push(self, element):
        self.stack.append(element)
        clearScreen()
        print("\n \t Element was inserted! \n\n")
        sleep(1)
        clearScreen()
        print(" \t Elements in the stack are: \n ")
        for i in range (len(self.stack)-1, -1, -1):
                print("\t \t",self.stack[i])
    
        sleep(1)
        input("\n \n \n Press enter key to exit..")
        clearScreen()

    def pop(self):
        if self.isEmpty():
            print("\n \t The stack is empty.")
            sleep(1)
            input("\n \n \n Press enter key to exit..")
            clearScreen()
        else:
            print("\n \n \t Deleted element is: ", self.stack.pop())
            sleep(1)
            print("\n \n \t Updated Elements in the stack: \n")
            for i in range (len(self.stack)-1, -1, -1):
                print("\t \t",self.stack[i])
            sleep(1)
            input("\n \n \n Press enter key to exit..")
            clearScreen()

    def peek(self):
        if self.isEmpty():
            print("\n \t The stack is empty.")
            sleep(1)
            input("\n \n \n Press enter key to exit..")
            clearScreen()
        else:
            print("\n \n \t Peek element is:", self.stack[-1])
            sleep(1)
            input("\n \n \n Press enter key to exit..")
            clearScreen()   

    def display(self):
        if self.isEmpty():
            print("\n \t The stack is empty.")
            sleep(1)
            input("\n \n \n Press enter key to exit..")
            clearScreen()
        else:
            print("\n \n \t Elements in the stack: \n")
            for i in range (len(self.stack)-1, -1, -1):
                print("\t \t",self.stack[i])
            
            sleep(1)
            input("\n \n \n Press enter key to exit..")
            clearScreen()
    
    class CopyStack():
    
        def copyOfStack(self):
           
            source = Stack()
            copySource = source.stack.copy()
            print(copySource)
```

Comment: Your code is wrongly formatted and does not compile. Please fix.

Answer (score 0):

To me this seems like it might be because you aren't actually copying a pre-existing stack.

I am going to assume that you were trying to run the `copyOfStack` method of a `CopyStack` class instance.

This method creates a new `Stack` object and copies from that. I imagine you want to copy from a pre-existing Stack object. In that case, I suggest the following change to your code:

```
class CopyStack():
    def copyOfStack(self, source: Stack):
        copySource = source.stack.copy()
        print(copySource)
```

And somewhere in your main function, instead of doing `CopyStack().copyOfStack()`, try using `CopyStack().copyOfStack(source)`.

Comment: i tried doing that, but it showed an error "copySource = source.stack.copy() AttributeError: type object 'Stack' has no attribute 'stack'."

Comment: Which python version are you using? Note the colon, not an equals sign, in `source: Stack`. Are you intializing your `source` object and passing it to `copyOfStack`?